# Codeigniter AJAX request to custom folder

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I created a new folder in my `application` directory called `scripts`.

The path to this folder is `[::1]/development/application/scripts/`. I would like to make ajax requests to script files in this folder.

Here is my request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "<?=site_url('application/scripts/center_contacts_server_processing.php')?>",
    success: function(resp) {
        console.log(resp)
    }
});
console.log("<?=site_url('application/scripts/center_contacts_server_processing.php')?>");
```

center_contacts_server_processing.php

```
<?php
    echo 'hi';
?>
```

And the output:

```
http://[::1]/development/application/scripts/center_contacts_server_processing.php
http://[::1]/development/application/scripts/center_contacts_server_processing.php 403 (Forbidden)
```

**Note**: I use ajax all around my site but I usually call controllers.

Comment: What is you'r problem?

Comment: set your `base_url` first in config.php as `http://localhost/project_name/`

Comment: check the current base url then try to map the directory location.

Comment: You need to put that folder outside your `application` folder(1 level up)

Comment: `base_url` is set. And I don't want my scripts outside my application folder. They are sensitive. I can't allow direct access.